# How to troubleshoot UnauthorizedAccessException when calling ManagementScope.Connect()

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, wmi, access-denied, dcom

I am looking for ideas to gather more information from the system about why a remote WMI call is failing.

The detailed steps in [Which permissions/rights does a user need to have WMI access on remote machines?](https://serverfault.com/questions/28520/which-permissions-rights-does-a-user-need-to-have-wmi-access-on-remote-machines) were helpful, but either I've accidentally missed something or there is something more that needs to be configured for my environment.

I am seeing the following exception when I run the .NET 4.0 C# code (snippet below):

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException occurred   Message=Access is
>   denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
>   Source=System.Management   StackTrace:
>          at System.Management.ThreadDispatch.Start()
>          at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()
>          at System.Management.ManagementScope.Connect()
>          at MyNamespace.MyClass.GetWmiInfo() in...

This is the code where the error occurs. The exception is thrown on the call to [Connect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.managementscope.connect.aspx).

```
var scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\HOSTNAME\\root\\cimv2")
{
    Options =
    {
        Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
        Password = "password",
        Username = "domain\\username"
    }
};

scope.Connect();
```

The code is being run on a Windows 7 computer, and the target of the WMI connection is a Windows XP computer. *Note: I see a similar problem if I reverse the two roles.*

I don't see any errors logged in the target computer's security log.

If I add the user whose credentials are being used to the Administrators group on the target computer, the call to `Connect()` succeeds, so the problem does seem to really be due to a privilege or access which is not yet granted.

Normally when I encounter access-denied errors I would be able to find an entry in a log that gives more detail, or would be able to run **regmon** or **filemon** to capture some useful information. But with this WMI / DCOM error, I don't know where else to look for more information.

Any suggestions much appreciated!

**Update:** I tested using [WBEMTest.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc180684.aspx) and found that access is also denied, unless I run as an administrator. I am trying to continue working with this tool to further isolate the problem.

Comment: Anything in the event log on the target machine?

Comment: There appar to be some clues here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/cbd93b81-2c23-4363-a00e-f702d6fa1349